# Валидация инпутов

Tags: javascript, dom

помогите решить задачу. Решил сделать рандомайзер и вот на пол пути столкнулся проблемой, никак не могу решить. Вот что я смог сделать

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.addBtn');
const cardBody = document.querySelector('.card-body');
const addAll = document.querySelector('.addAll');
const inputArr = [];
let currentIn = 1;

addBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let count = +prompt('Введите количество участников', '2');

    if(count == 0 || count == 1){
        alert("Количество участников не может быть пустым или равно к единице!");
    }else {
        let input;
        for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
            input = `<input class="form-control mb-3 inputs" id="${currentIn}" placeholder="Имя участника №${currentIn}">`;
            inputArr.push(input);
            currentIn++;
        }

        inputLoad();

        addAll.style.display = "block";
        addBtn.style.display = "none";
    }
});

let counter = 0;
let inValues = [];

addAll.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
   
    let input = cardBody.querySelectorAll('.inputs');

    if(counter < input.length){
        if(input[counter].value == ""){
            alert("Заполните все поля");
        }else {
            counter = 0;
            for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
                inValues.push(input[i].value);
            }
        }

        counter++;
    }
});

const inputLoad = () => {
    cardBody.innerHTML = inputArr;
    let input = cardBody.querySelectorAll('.inputs');

    for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if(input[i].nextSibling){
            input[i].nextSibling.remove();
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Randomizer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body class="bg-light">

    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="card text-center w-50">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title m-0">Randomizer</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4>Список участников пуст!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button class="btn btn-danger addBtn">Добавить участников</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success addAll">Добавить всех участников</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

застрял на событии клик к addAll. Я хотел чтобы оно согласовалось к этой правиле. У инпутов должна быть валидация заполнение всех инпутов именами (то есть, если хоть на один инпут ничего не ввести, то программа должна вывести предупреждение - alert). А у меня это работает не корректно как исправить? Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addAll.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let input = cardBody.querySelectorAll('.inputs');
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) { 
    if (input[i].value == "") {
      alert("Заполните все поля");
      return;
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
     inValues.push(input[i].value);
  }
});
```